# Black Desktop Background - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I've had this problem since my last build. I've got all new parts aside from my psu. I thought it was my gpu that was causing the issue but I swapped to an AMD temporarily and it still happens. My background will go black and I can get it back by restarting Windows Explorer, but that's a hassle for as often as it happens. It used to freeze in my old build but I haven't seen that happen yet, with this new GPU. Any ideas?

Comment: Background goes black is ambiguous. Do you mean the color turns black but icons are still visible or that the screen goes blank?  I don't have an answer but I wouldn't have a hope of having one without knowing what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The icons are available but the background goes black. Before I swapped GPUs I could get it back by highlighting the desktop and it would show the BG in chunks where I highlighted.